# PHP zipping ends with Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, unix, zip

I have a php script on my server that zips a few directories into 1 zip file. Normally, everything runs fine. Today, it's taking longer than usually and then ends with a page that says "Internal Server Error".

When I check the directory where the zip gets created, it seems the zip made it about half way there (as the file is about half the size it should be and is corrupted).

In my logs, I see this as the error:
mod_fcgid: process 30172 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL

Any ideas what the problem is?

This is the code I'm using (and note that it works fine most of the time):

```
$zipFolders[] = 'httpdocs/';
$zipFolders[] = 'includes/';

$zip = new ZipArchive();

if ($zip->open($sourceFileName, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) die ("Could not open archive");

foreach ($zipFolders as $zipFolder) 
{
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($zipFolder));

    foreach ($iterator as $key=>$value) 
    {
        if ( (substr($key, -1) != '.')&&(substr($key, -2) != '..') ) {          
            $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key"); 
        }
    }
}

$zip->close();
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please share relevant code

Comment: Turn on error reporting (add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to your script) and post the relevant code here.

Comment: Ok, I put the code up

Comment: You could be running into a memory or time limit if the files are big.

Comment: @Barmar - that's what I was thinking. Is there anything I can do to allocate this 1 script more memory?